# addslashes() only if slashes are not added from before

Tags: php, php-5.3

I'm getting a lot of text values from my database that I need to output with slashes added before characters that need to be quoted.

Problem is that some of the data already has the slashes added there from before, whilst some of it doesn't.

How can I add slashes using for example addslashes() - but at the same time make sure that it doesn't add an extra slash in the cases where the slash is already added?

Example:

```
Input: <a href="test.html">test</a>
Output should be: <a href=\"test.html\">test</a>

Input: <a href=\"test.html\">test</a>
Output should be: <a href=\"test.html\">test</a>
```

This is PHP 5.3.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you don't have any double slashes, simply run `addslashes()` and then replace all `\\` with `\`.

Comment: If there is the possibility of having more than 2 backslashes, consider using a recursive function and checking with `strpos()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this:

```
<a href=\"test.html\">test</a>
```

Using addslashes(), the output will be:

```
<a href=\\\"test.html\\\">test</a>
```

So, you may need to replace every occurrence of more than one \ to be sure

Answer (score 1):

### **First option :**

If you want to escape both single and double quotes. Ignoring already escaped quotes

```
function escape_quotes($string) {
    return preg_replace("/(^|[^\\\\])(\"|')/","$1\\\\$2", $string);
}
```

*Input*

> I love "carots" but "I" don't like 'cherries'

*Output*

> I love "carots" but "I" don't like 'cherries'

***Explanation :***

The `\` has a special meaning inside a quoted expression and will escape the following character in the string, so while you would need to write `\\` in a regex to search for the backslash character, in php you need to escape those two backslashes also, adding up to a total of 4 backslashes.

So with that in mind, the first capturing group then searches for a single character that is not a backslash or is the start of the string (and not two or four backslashes as misleading as it is)

The second capturing group will search for a double or a single quote exactly once.

So this finds unescaped quotes (double and single) and add a backslash before the quote thus escaping it.

[image: Regex visual explanation]

### **Second option :**

It might just be best for you to convert them to html entities from the start :

```
function htmlentities_quotes($string) {
    return str_replace(array('"', "'"), array("&quot;", "&apos;"), $string);
}
```

And then you just have to use the php function `htmlspecialchars_decode($string);` to revert it back to how it was.

*Input*

> I love "carots" but "I" don't like 'cherries'

*Output*

> I love `&quot;`carots`&quot;` but `&quot;`I`&quot;` don`&apos;`t like
> `&apos;`cherries`&apos;`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think at least the first code block needs explanation (especially the used regex).

Comment: @BDL Done with the explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
function addslashes($string) {
    return preg_replace('/([^\\\\])\"/','$1\"',$string);
}
```